# Subtract a counter from another in plain tex

Tags: counters, plain-tex

I'm sure this is very easy, but searching the internet I came up with nothing, and reading the TeXbook, I learned so much other stuff that I forgot what I was originally looking for ;-)

So, I just want to set the value of a counter to the difference of the values of two other counters in plain TeX, like this:

```
\newcount\countOne%
\newcount\countTwo%
\newcount\diff%
\diff=\countOne-\countTwo\relax%
```

Only, this doesn't work, ending up with "missing number, treated as zero"...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\diff=\countOne
\advance\diff-\countTwo
```

Comment: That was extremely fast!! I knew it was easy... Thanks! Sorry, can't upvote due to low reputation.

Answer (score 6):

That would be

```
\diff=\countOne
\advance\diff-\countTwo
```

Comment: I'll accept David Carlisle's answer as it was a little faster, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

For the case that e-TeX is available (`\numexpr`):

```
\newcount\countOne
\newcount\countTwo
\newcount\diff
\diff=\numexpr\countOne-\countTwo\relax
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the examples given here are no MWE, I wasn't really able to test them. So, here is another code (but a MWE) that works as well:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{FirstCounter}
\setcounter{FirstCounter}{42}
\newcounter{SecondCounter}
\setcounter{SecondCounter}{23}

\newcounter{FirstMinusSecondCounter}
\setcounter{FirstMinusSecondCounter}{%
  \numexpr\value{FirstCounter}-\value{SecondCounter}%
}

\noindent %just for a nicer output...
1st Counter: \theFirstCounter\\
2nd Counter: \theSecondCounter\\
1st minus 2nd: \theFirstMinusSecondCounter

\end{document}
```

(based upon an answer to this related question about [adding numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393784/how-can-i-sum-two-numbers-in-latex-with-my-own-command))

Comment: The question was about plain TeX, not LaTeX.

Comment: O, yeah, now that you mention it... I guess I didn't realize this since I was focusing too much on solving my problem (with LaTeX)...